# Add link next to "Your order" text on the checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a simple cart link next to "Your Order" so customers can go back to cart if a change is needed. I have this, and it works:

```
// adds edit cart link on Checkout page
function custom_wc_translations($translated){
$text = array(
'Your order' => 'Your Order <a class="ck-order-cart-link" href="/cart/">Edit Cart</a>',
);
$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20 );
```

But strangely, in injects...

```
<a class="ck-order-cart-link" href="/cart/">Edit Cart</a>
```

...into the placeholder of the "order notes" field.

I also tried this syntax variation with no luck:

```
// adds edit cart link on Checkout page
function custom_wc_translations($translated){
$text = array(
'Your order' => "Your Order <a class='ck-order-cart-link' href='/cart/'>Edit Cart</a>",
);
$translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20 );
```

Any suggestion on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score -1):

**The best way for you to do is to override the template file**

What you are doing is wrong. You are searching for the string **Your order** in the translated text array and replace it with your text. So the **order note** placeholder contain the string **Notes about Your Order, e.g. special notes for delivery.** which contain the string **Your order** , which is being replaced by your replace function. That's what injects the string into **order note** field. Try the following.

```
function custom_wc_translations( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  if(is_checkout()){
    switch ($translated_text) {
      case 'Your order' :
        $translated_text = "Your Order <a class='ck-order-cart-link' href='/cart/'>Edit Cart</a>";
        break;
    }
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20, 3 );
```